# Associating child to it's parent's parent?

Tags: associations, odoo

In OpenERP I have 3 models, A, B and C. If you start on the form for A, there is a tree list of children B. when you click on one of those B children that form has a tree list of children C. I need the C children to be associated to both parents A and B but they will only associate themselves with B despite having many2one fields for both A and B. How can I force this association? 
I have looked at solutions using active_id and default_get without success. The context object seems useful for this but I see no way of dynamically setting it with ids for both parent objects as I drill down from A to C navigating through the forms. I don't understand why context is not normally used for holding the context in this manner like in various web frameworks.

To clarify, when I edit object A and from it's edit form create an instance of B and from B's edit form create an instance of C how do I make the C associated to A and B?

Should I just execute a simple update with subselect query in C's create method to make this happen or will that break the ORM?

Looking at the transaction data when I save a new C instance (document) I see that everything I need in terms of ids is within the transaction but I don't know how to access and manipulate the values as I need to e.g.

```
{
   "jsonrpc":"2.0",
   "method":"call",
   "params":{
      "model":"dbe.vendor",
      "method":"write",
      "args":[
         [
            3
         ],
         {
            "application":[
               [
                  4,
                  2,
                  false
               ],
               [
                  1,
                  21,
                  {
                     "documents":[
                        [
                           4,
                           37,
                           false
                        ],
                        [
                           4,
                           35,
                           false
                        ],
                        [
                           4,
                           46,
                           false
                        ],
                        [
                           4,
                           36,
                           false
                        ],
                        [
                           0,
                           false,
                           {
                              "state":"new",
                              "name":"order of precendence test",
                              "description":"TESTING",
                              "type_of":7,
                              "locked":false,
                              "note":false,
                              "datas":false,
                              "datas_fname":false,
                              "type":"binary",
                              "application_id":false,
                              "certification_id":false,
                              "vendor_id":3,
                              "message_follower_ids":false,
                              "message_ids":false
                           }
                        ]
                     ]
                  }
               ]
            ]
         }
      ],
      "kwargs":{
         "context":{
            "lang":"en_US",
            "tz":"EST",
            "uid":7
         }
      },
      "session_id":"303ae4c1bd9d49079c4efc9e06e0184f",
      "context":{
         "lang":"en_US",
         "tz":"EST",
         "uid":7
      }
   },
   "id":"r138"
}
```

NOTE: I manually inserted vendor_id because it is a required field but it is the field I want to automatically populated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps I am not literate enough with OpenERP to make this association happen properly or there isn't enough relevant documentation or the ORM isn't designed for this use (or any combinations of these) but I need this to work as per my requirements and now it does. I apologize if it is offensive in any manner. Criticisms and advice always welcome.

```
def create(self, cr, uid, vals, context=None):
    """Creates a new dbe.document instance. Called by both internal app and client.
       documents are associated to dbe.vendor, dbe.application and dbe.certification.
    @param vals: All dbe.document field values as a dictionary.
    @return ID of new dbe.document instance.
    """
    if context is None:
        context={}

    doc_id = None
    association_id = None
    # vendor_id is passed with vals when documents are created from the client side. 
    new_vendor_id = vals.get('vendor_id',False)
    if new_vendor_id:
        doc_id = super(dbe_document,self).create(cr, uid, vals, context=context)
        _logger.debug("<CREATE> DBE Document (%d) created for vendor #%d by user %d", doc_id, new_vendor_id, uid)
    else: # within OpenERP we cannot get vendor_id from context so we do it caveman style.
        doc_id = super(dbe_document,self).create(cr, uid, vals, context=context)
        association_id = self.read(cr, uid, doc_id, ['application_id', 'certification_id'], context=context)
        if association_id['application_id']:
            application_id = association_id['application_id']
            application_obj = self.pool.get('dbe.application')
            application = application_obj.browse(cr, uid, application_id)
            new_vendor_id = application.vendor_id.id
        elif association_id['certification_id']: # since there is no application maybe its a certification related doc....
            certification_id = association_id['certification_id'][0]
            certification_obj = self.pool.get('dbe.certification')
            certification = certification_obj.browse(cr, uid, certification_id)
            new_vendor_id = certification.vendor_id.id
        else:
            raise osv.except_osv(_('ValidateError'), _('<CREATE> A DBE Document cannot be created without an application or certification - Association Missing!'))

        if new_vendor_id: # brute-force association to dbe.vendor.
            vals.update({'vendor_id': new_vendor_id})
            self.write(cr, uid, doc_id, vals, context)
            _logger.debug("<CREATE> DBE Document (%d) created for vendor #%d by user %d", doc_id, new_vendor_id, uid)
        else: # too bad - no vendor, no doc.
            _logger.debug("<CREATE> DBE Document (%d) removed because vendor_id missing for user %d", doc_id, uid)
            raise osv.except_osv(_('ValidateError'), _('<CREATE> A DBE Document cannot be created without selecting a Vendor - Vendor Id Missing!'))

    return doc_id
```

Answer (score 0):

better to use fields.related to make such association where you can do refer "A" from "B" in form of "C".

Comment: The idea is to not need to manually select the association from the edit/create form and to have the super-parent FK in the actual DB record. This is crucial as external applications will be using the same tables from a replicated DB. OpenERP ORM magic will not be available to external apps.

Comment: In related fields you don't have to select anything.